# Subsetting a Data Table using %in%

Tags: r, data.table

A stylized version of my data.table is

```
outmat <- data.table(merge(merge(1:5, 1:5, all=TRUE), 1:5, all=TRUE))
```

What I would like to do is select a subset of rows from this data.table based on whether the value in the 1st column is found in any of the other columns (it will be handling matrices of unknown dimension, so I can't just use some sort of "row1 == row2 | row1 == row3"

I wanted to do this using

```
output[row1 %in% names(output)[-1], ]
```

but this ends up returning TRUE if the value in row1 is found in any of the rows of row2 or row3, which is not the intended behavior.  It there some sort of vectorized version of %in% that will achieve my desired result?

To elaborate, what I want to get is the enumeration of 3-tuples from the set 1:5, drawn with replacement, such that the first value is the same as either the second or third value, something like:

1 1 1
1 1 2
1 1 3
1 1 4
1 1 5
...
2 1 2
2 2 1
...
5 5 5

What my code instead gives me is every enumeration of 3-tuples, as it is checking whether the first digit (say, 5), ever appears anywhere in the 2rd or 3rd columns, not simply within the same row.

Comment: I did notice a misplaced ) in my original, but I'm unfamiliar with the CJ function.  My intention was for the example to enumerate all combinations of 3 numbers drawn from 1 to 5, with replacement.

Comment: Ok, just noticed that parentheses.  Can you show the expected output based on the input data. as the comparison you mentioned is confusing.

Comment: I've tried to explain the desired output more clearly.  It's a bit easier to explain in words: enumerate all sequences of N dice rolls such that the first roll's value is repeated at least once.  In my example, N was 3, but I would like for this to scale, hence my interest in using some variant of %in%.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to construct the expression and evaluate it:

```
dt = data.table(a = 1:5, b = c(1,2,4,3,1), c = c(4,2,3,2,2), d = 5:1)
#   a b c d
#1: 1 1 4 5
#2: 2 2 2 4
#3: 3 4 3 3
#4: 4 3 2 2
#5: 5 1 2 1

expr = paste(paste(names(dt)[-1], collapse = paste0(" == ", names(dt)[1], " | ")),
             "==", names(dt)[1])
#[1] "b == a | c == a | d == a"

dt[eval(parse(text = expr))]
#   a b c d
#1: 1 1 4 5
#2: 2 2 2 4
#3: 3 4 3 3
```

Another option is to just loop through and compare the columns:

```
dt[rowSums(sapply(dt, '==', dt[[1]])) > 1]
#   a b c d
#1: 1 1 4 5
#2: 2 2 2 4
#3: 3 4 3 3
```

Comment: just wonder about your first solution, couldn't this be done using language objects instead of parsing characater?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean. Can you give an example?

Comment: using `call` or `as.call` on symbols and expressions instead of parse on string, but cannot figured out this example

Comment: I guess you could construct a list with appropriate elements to form the call, but what would be the point?

Comment: Avoid parsing character string which is a little less secure?

Comment: I don't get it - why is it any less secure than typing those same characters (i.e. what you normally do when you run commands)? Do you have an example of issues in mind?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91133/discussion-between-jangorecki-and-eddi).

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dt %>%
  mutate(ID = 1:n() )
  gather(variable, value, -first_column, -ID) %>%
  filter(first_column == value) %>%
  select(ID) %>%
  distinct %>%
  left_join(dt)
```